# Mapbox - Failed resolution of LostLocationEngine

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-android

When I try to start navigation:

```
MapboxNavigation navigation = new MapboxNavigation(this, Mapbox.getAccessToken(), options);
navigation.startNavigation(route);
```

I get the following error on runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapbox/services/android/telemetry/location/LostLocationEngine;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LostLocationEngine"
```

Indeed I am not able to import the class from that location, however the LocationEngine is available from `com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine`. I think it might have something to do with the dependencies. This is what I build from mapbox in my Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.12.0'
```

How can I solve this so I can start navigation in my app?

Comment: Curious, are you using ProGuard?

Comment: Which version of mapbox are you using ?

Comment: @stkent minifyEnabled is set to false, so I think I'm not using ProGuard.

Comment: @xiaomi The lines mentioned in the post are all I have concerning mapbox. So I think that gives me mapbox version 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL:DR**

Use the version [0.13.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android#using-snapshots)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.13.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

**Explanation**

The problem is that `LocationLayer` and `Places` are using Mapbox 6 ([LocationLayer 0.5.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/v0.5.0-location-layer/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L11), [Places 0.3.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/v0.3.0-places/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L11)), but the navigation is using Mapbox 5 ([Navigation 0.12.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/v0.12.0/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L11)).

When you combine these 3 libraries, Gradle will try to use the latest version of a dependencies when 2 libraries shared the same.

In our case, the `mapbox-android-telemetry` will be upgrade from 2.2.10 to 3.0.2. This is why when the nagivation tries to find `LostLocationEngine` under `com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location` (v2) it fails, because this classed move to `com.mapbox.services.android.location` (v3).

If you want to know how to check the dependencies version, [look here](https://www.devsbedevin.com/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/)

Answer (score 0):

add this lines to your gradle or if you already have mapbox-android-services, then change its version to 2.2.9.

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.9@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```